# FireMonkey FlowLayout isn't refreshing items based on visible property

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

How are you? Hope you doing fine.
My question: I have a FlowLayout with a lot of layouts inside it, and I need to hide a few based on a radio button selection, in design time it works fine I set the visible property to false and all the other layouts realign the right way, but when I do this at runtime it doesn't work, it keeps a white gap between the layout that has been hidden and the next one. When I do a resize manually (go to the form border and drag a little) it realigns and gets right, but if I select another radio the layout gets back and it override another layout so I need to resize manually again to realign. I tried to look at the source code of Resize but I got nothing relevant. What I tried: Repaint, Realign, InvalidateRect, RecalcAbsolute. Is there any way that I have to force the refresh of components?

```
procedure
    TFrmApontamentoProducaoOrdemProducao.rbOrdensProducaoQuantidadeParcialClick(
    Sender: TObject);
begin
  if not lytQuantidadeParcial.Visible then
    lytQuantidadeParcial.Visible := True;
  // Tried to realign here
end;

procedure
    TFrmApontamentoProducaoOrdemProducao.rbOrdensProducaoQuantidadeTotalClick(
    Sender: TObject);
begin
  if lytQuantidadeParcial.Visible then
    lytQuantidadeParcial.Visible := False;
  // Tried to realign here
end;
```

It's a simple code, but it's giving me a little problem. Thanks for the help, if you need more code or more details just let me know.

Comment: Please show what you have tried (as commented out lines is fine). What exactly to you try to Repaint, for example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must surround your code that makes changes to the layout of the `TFlowLayout` with a pair of `FlowLayout1.BeginUpdate;` and `FlowLayout1.EndUpdate;` To assure that the update counter stays in sync, you should also use a `try..finally..end` block.

For example

```
procedure TForm21.Button6Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FlowLayout1.BeginUpdate;
  try
    Layout3.Visible := not Layout3.Visible;
  finally
    FlowLayout1.EndUpdate;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Thank you so much man Tom. I tried many things to update the visual and none of them worked. I'm really grateful.

Answer (score 0):

Using BeginUpdate cause access violation on a project when insert chars from tcp-ip comunication in real time on FlowLayout, the solution:

```pascal
var
PodeAtualizarGrade:TCriticalSection;
// ...

FormCreate
PodeAtualizarGrade:=TCriticalSection.Create;
// ...


PodeAtualizarGrade.Enter;

(FlowLayout.AddObjects)

PodeAtualizarGrade.Leave;
```

Works fine on my project.